# Have the Elementor Addon 'Table of Content' feature initially display as the button, not the opened panel

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I really like the EA 'Table of Content'. Info on it here: https://essential-addons.com/elementor/docs/table-of-content/

The problem is that when a person visits the page with the TOC enabled, the TOC opens fully which covers the text on the page. So the user has to close the TOC to read the content. Depending on your site design, this is not a problem on desktops.

But it is a real problem on mobile devices - most of the page gets covered.

All I want is the TOC to display as the standard collapsed button on the side. Then, if the user wants to look at the TOC, they can click on the button and it will open as normal.

That is, the initial state of the TOC should be **closed** (showing just the button on the side).

Is this possible?

[This is how I want the control to initially display on the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95QrQ.png)

Comment: I am also interested in this. I believe this is a class "collapsed" which should be added on page load, to the div "eael-toc".

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possibility using HTML5:

```
document.getElementById("eael-toc").classList.toggle('collapsed');
```